# aws node.js pass contents of xml as JSON stringify

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Node.js 6.10

Process is as follows...

1) Dropped an XML file into an S3 bucket.
2) Triggered a lambda,
3) Called a step function, which calls another lambda
4) This lambda captures the XML from the bucket with

```
var s3Bucket = new aws.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'bucketName'} } );
var xmlFile = s3Bucket.getObject('fileName.xml');
```

5) send an email with the contents of the XML as a string

```
  let index = function index(event, context, callback) {

    var fileName = event.fileName;
    var bucketName = event.bucketName;
    var todaysDate = event.todaysDate;

    var eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["emailAddress"]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                //Text: { Data: 'file: ' + fileName + ' bucketName: ' + bucketName + ' todaysDate: ' + todaysDate}
                Text: { Data: 'file: ' + JSON.stringify(xmlFile)}
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: "Email Subject!!!"
            }
        },
        Source: "emailAddress"
    };

    console.log('===SENDING EMAIL===');
    var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("===EMAIL SENT===");
            console.log(data);
            console.log("EMAIL CODE END");
            console.log('EMAIL: ', email);
            context.succeed(event);
        }
    });
};

module.exports.init = (event, context, callback) => {
};
exports.handler = index;
```

I know the sending an email works because if I uncomment the line

```
Text: { Data: 'fileName: ' + fileName + ' bucketName: ' + bucketName + ' todaysDate: ' + todaysDate}
```

and comment out `Text: { Data: 'file: ' + JSON.stringify(xmlFile)}`

it sends the email with the correct filename, bucketName, and date

So when I try to include `Text: { Data: 'file: ' + JSON.stringify(xmlFile)}`

the logs show the error

> ypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native) at index (/var/task/index.js:39:51)

**UPDATE**
Thanks @Michael & @Khand for the replies. I have tried what you suggested

```
  var params = {
  Bucket: "bucketName", 
  Key: "fileName.xml"
 };
 s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) 
 {
   if (err) 
   {
       console.log(err, err.stack); 
   }// an error occurred
   else     
   {
       console.log("Returned data object " + data);           // successful response
       console.log("Returned xml " + data.body);
   }
```

console is returning 

`Returned data object [object Object]
Returned xml undefined`

and yes the bucket does contain the named file. The [object, object] is populated but the body tag is undefined

Comment: Do you want to send just the content of the xml file or the object returned by `getObject`?

Comment: hey Khand, thanks for the reply...the object returned by getObject is an xml file. I want to send the content of this file...I have looked into json-stringify-safe but with no success. it tells me "Cannot find module 'json-stringify-safe'", I dont think is is available with lambda, node.js

Comment: There are a couple of problems, here.  `var xmlFile = s3Bucket.getObject('fileName.xml');` is not how you use `getObject()`, it's asynchronous... see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property... `data.Body` will contain the XML payload.

Comment: `getObject` does not only return xml file content, it returns an de-serialized object of the response message from S3. The file content should be stored in `obj.Body`, you can check out the full object here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the reply please see my update of OP

Comment: @khang, thanks for the reply please see my update of OP

Comment: It should be `data.Body`, read the docs dude

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I read the documents but I can see form my returned value that data.body is undefined

Comment: @John Yes. data.body is undefined but you should use data.Body. I.e instead of 'body' you should use 'Body'.